# Can I find the text with chain of narrations for the books of Hadith online and in English?

Tags: hadith, sunnah, sahih-bukhari

I want the complete text for the books of Hadith:

- Sahih Bukhari
- Sahih Muslim
- Sunan Abu Dawood
- Jami al-Tirmidhi
- Sunan al-Sughra
- Sunan ibn Majah

In English (and arabic). Does such a resource exist online? I looked at http://sunnah.com/bukhari/1 but it does not have the complete chain of narration. The same is true of http://www.usc.edu/org/cmje/religious-texts/hadith/bukhari/001-sbt.php

So if someone could please share an online resource, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: English: you can only find a pdf version. Arabic: filter by book's name http://library.islamweb.net/hadith/index.php

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because book recommendations are currently off-topic on the site. http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/261/3487

Answer (score -6):

Of course, check these links:

- http://sunnah.com/
- http://www.quranexplorer.com/Hadith/English/Index.html

Comment: OP clearly dismissed sunnah.com (at least regarding Bukhari) as insufficient for his needs.  And the quranexplorer link explicitly mentions that it only contains a *partial* collection of Abu Dawood, and only *two* of the books that OP is looking for otherwise (and what I've seen, what it provides is even *less* complete than sunnah.com).